# highly unstable 4k 60Hz monitor display ubuntu 20.04

Tags: display, 20.04, nvidia-geforce, 4k-monitor

I have a monitor U32J59 from samsung that I was using with windows computer just before. It worked just fine.
I am now using my Ubuntu desktop and I have huge issues making it working at 4k 60hz. The `xrandr` command returns :

```
DVI-D-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.94    50.00    30.00*   29.97    25.00    23.98  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and I have got a GeForce GTX 1060 6GB.

I can go UHD 30Hz without any issue, but as soon as i select 60Hz in settings menu, or nvidia x server settings menu or run the command `xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60`, the screen goes black half of the time and when it's working (for like half a second) I've got horizontal red lines over my display.

I have the same issues when selecting 59.94Hz or 50Hz
Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed my cable, used a HDMI-HDMI instead of DVI-HDMI and it worked right away.. :)

Comment: Are you overall satisfied with this specific monitor model with Ubuntu? any issues?

Comment: It works just fine. The only thing that bothers be a bit is that sometimes I want to split 3-4 windows around my screen and i had to download extension with gnome-tweak-tools.

Comment: You mean an extension that makes each window take up precisely one quarter rather than hand-sizing each window? Did you manage 4K resolution with this monitor?

Comment: I did manage 4k resolution, you have to use correct cable (needs to support 4k), you need to connect it to the right ports (4k 60Hz on screen, the other has a lower bandwidth), AND you have to use the right driver (I can tell you if you need which one i picked)

Comment: Well, as I'm getting one this week, I am happy to abuse this thread in a minor way and ask for the driver, as it sounds like avoiding to fiddle picking a special driver from scratch is really a rescue.

Comment: the nvidia-driver-440 works for me :)